# SOLVED - blank react page when trying to render an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a blank react page when trying to render an image. I am using the @material-ui/core package and it installed correctly.

Here is the code I am using.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import memories from './images/memories.png';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
                <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
                <img src={memories} alt ="memories" heigth="60"/>
            </AppBar>
        </Container>
       
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is what I am getting in the debugging console:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at  (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the material-ui package, checked the syntax and made sure the "memories.png" image is in the right location.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What do you see in your console logs?

Comment: @DSteman i am getting this from the debugging console: Uncaught SyntaxError /memories/client/my-app/src/App.js:1
import React from 'react';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)

Comment: @DSteman could it be a syntax error? the code compiles without any issues

Comment: Place put your code in the question like suggested by @David along with that traceback from the console. How did you initialize your React project?

Comment: @DSteman thanks for your reply, I just pasted the code and the console traceback. I initialed my project from VS code using create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing components incorrectly. According to the [documentation of MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-container/#main-content) you have to import a `Container` from `@mui/material/Container` for example. Probably you are seeing errors about this in the React logs as well(?) Check out the docs for each component, they all have code snippets that show how to import.

Comment: thanks, I just tried import { Container } from '@mui/material'; and getting this error in the terminal: 

Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in '/client/my-app/src'
WARNING in [eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 2:10:  'Container' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material' in '/client/my-app/src'

webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code using import from '@mui/material';

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import { AppBar } from '@mui/material';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

import memories from './images/memories.png';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Container maxwidth="lg">
            <AppBar position="static" color='inherit'>
                <Typography variant="h2" align='center'>Memories</Typography>
                <img src={memories} alt='memories' height="60"/>
            </AppBar>
        </Container>
       
    );
}

export default App;
```

however I am still getting a blank react page and the same logs in my console:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module at compileFunction (vm:360:18) at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27) at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12) at (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)

Comment: your updated code works fine. refer to this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-galileo-76g719

Comment: hi @Arjun thanks for your reply, i just checked and it does work on the sandbox. for some reason it does not work on my local host when i launch my react app from VS code, any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Try clearing node_modules, package-lock.json and install again. If that doesn't help you, share your code structure . or you can compare your code with the shared sandbox, check package.json .

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked after clearing those!

Comment: You can edit your question instead of posting an answer as an update of your question